# Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$unwind'

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I am trying to do an aggregation using this array:

```
[
            [
                '$match' => ['deck_id' => 18],
            ],
            [
                '$project' => [
                    'stack' => 1,
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$unwind' => '$stack'
            ],
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => '$stack.response',
                    'responses' => [
                        '$push' => '$$ROOT.stack'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$project' => [
                    'responses_count' => ['$size' => '$responses']
                ]
            ]
        ]
```

But I am getting the following exception:
**Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$unwind'**

I also created an issue in GitHub with this error. I am using mongodb 4 and the latest mongodb extension from pecl.

https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/935

The following query works without error on Mongo Clients for example, but not in PHP:

```
db.getCollection('game_statistics').aggregate([
    {$match: {deck_id: 18}},
    {$project: {stack: 1}},
    {$unwind: "$stack"},
    {$group: {_id: "$stack.response", responses: {$push: "$$ROOT.stack"}}},
    {$project: {responses_count: {'$size': "$responses"}}}
])
```

Comment: So first of all. Wrong driver. Please read the [documentation from the official site](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/php/) which clearly states what everything is and where you install it from. Also, MongoDB has a JIRA system for all bugs, and any "official" repositories on GitHub are not actually open for lodging "issues".

Comment: ? It is not the wrong driver!

Comment: I have both installed, please do not think I am a newbie :) I am a senior and I am using the LIB through composer. That's where the exception comes from... Are you even familiar with the PHP extension and lib?

Comment: Extension version installed: 1.5.3, lib version installed: 1.4.2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182934/discussion-between-filip-and-neil-lunn).

Comment: This issue was also reported in the MongoDB JIRA issue tracker: [PHPLIB-396](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPLIB-396). The error turned out to be a result of spurious UTF-8 characters in the PHP script; removing those characters allows the script to run as intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on my side. Even though the code was correct, there were a series of invisible UTF8 chars in the array keys or values that the driver was taking into account. Opening that file with VIM allowed me to see those characters and removing them worked.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHPLIB-396